# Javascript Gets the contents of the textarea of the distance from the border pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I be sure the text in the input box, the number of pixels from the left box? It may have utf8, Chinese
[image]

Comment: how are you calculating this currently?

Comment: Calculation of the width of the content

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best way, but i guess this can be a start. This will return the number of pixels remaining in the input element:

```
function getRemainingWidth(element){
    var span = $('<span class=\"'+$(element).attr('class')+'\" style=\"visibility:hidden;\">'+$(element).val()+'</span>');
    $(document.body).append(span);
    var diff = $(element).width() - $(span).width();
    $(span).remove();
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: Please cache your selectors (not to mention the fact that there's no reason to constantly re-wrap the `span` in jQuery). Here you go: http://pastebin.com/bXpz1PZe

Comment: @JosephSilber. Sorry. Didn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is creating a `span` element and adding your text to it. But there is a catch: you have to add it to the dom in order get its with:

```
var sYourText = 'asdfafdsa, dzcvxvxc';
var oText = document.createElement('span');
oText.innerHTML = sYourText;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(oText)
console.log(oText.offsetWidth);
```

Of course: be sure to apply the same font that your textarea have.

Comment: Space appears and enter the text to wrap bug

Answer (score 0):

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
                var s = $(this).val()
                var data = s.replace(/(\s)/g,'&nbsp;')
                console.log(data)
                $('span').html(data)
            })
```

I replace it with a regular spaces replaced, but wrapping problems that may require using CSS